# PostgreSQL: Which datatype is better to use for this situation?

Tags: performance, postgresql, lookup-tables

I am building a database which will be used to define and keep track of a document used inside my organization. Each of these documents has a category associated with it. Will it be more efficient to store the category for each document as a "TEXT" in the main table, or will it be more efficient to store the category for each document as a "SMALLINT" and have a lookup table that equates that value with a "TEXT" field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not about efficiency. It is about referential integrity. Make the column in the main table to reference the category table.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity

Comment: But the question is should I make the category table to begin with, or simply put the category as a TEXT field in the main table?

Comment: @Jefferson You **must** make the category table. Without that reference the main table will turn into junk sooner or later.

Comment: As one slight note, you can have a category table with text values as primary keys and refer that way.  That optimizes selects if that's the concern since you don't need to join.

Comment: To clarify: a document can reside in only one category, but one category may contain many documents. So I need to create a table whose primary key is constrained to the Category column in the main table?

Comment: @Jefferson It is the opposite. The value on the main table is constrained to an existing value in the category table. Check the manual for the `create table` details. Create the category table first.